# Asp.net core 2.0 mvc application get client ip address with load balancer option

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am unable to get client IP address using .net core 2.0 application.

I used the below code in startup.cs file.

I used the below code in homecontriller.cs file.

I am getting remoteIpAddress is 1.0.0.0 in local. when I deployed in the server I got server IP address but I want to display the client IP address. 
can you please help with this. thanks.

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions> (options => {
 options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor> ();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor> ();


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
 app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
  ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
 });
}

public IActionResult Index() {
 string remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
 if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-For")) {
  remoteIpAddress = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
 }

 ViewBag.ip1 = remoteIpAddress.ToString();
 return View();
}
```

Comment: You have mentioned the filename but the not code itself, please add code.

Comment: I added code @YashKaranke

Comment: i posted my code @YashKaranke

Answer (score 0):

In project.json add a dependency to:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides": "1.0.0"
```

In Startup.cs, in the Configure() method add:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });
```

and in controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
```

then by this way you can get the IP address

```
Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
```

Comment: Thanks I have already tried below one but no use. Its giving server IP address rather than giving client machine IP address

Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress

Comment: @Harry, then refer this link i hope this will fix your issue                https://edi.wang/post/2017/10/16/get-client-ip-aspnet-20

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply. I have tried this one as well but giving same result.

Comment: If any other solutions, please let me know. Appreciate your help